# do we say "wrap it up" when we want our kids to stop playing games or watching TV?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

> [wrap up | wrap it up](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wrap-up) ​(slang) usually used as an order to tell
>   somebody to stop talking or causing trouble, etc.

---

Now it's time for lunch & your children are playing games, watching TV or doing homework etc actively without noticing their lunch time.

Can we say, "**ok, guys, wrap it up & go to lunch**".?

But seem "**wrap it up**" is mainly used to tell somebody to stop talking or causing trouble. I am not sure if it can be used for other activities such as watching TV, playing games, doing homework, etc

Comment: If the activity is ***filming a scene for a movie***, the director will often say something like *Okay guys, **it's a wrap***, rather than ***Let's wrap up*** (the usage tends to imply *reaching some useful end goal*, rather than simply "stopping"). But for your context, I'd say ***Knock it off!*** is a far more common way of informally telling others (usually, *of lower status*) to stop what they're doing. For a less "demeaning" alternative, perhaps ***Finish up now.***